Display maximum, minimum, mode values and model value in ridgeline plot
There is a tutorial by J. Schork and A. Molina on how to construct ridgeline plots (https://statisticsglobe.com/ridgeline-plots-in-r). Thanks for the tutorial.
The following code from the tutorial creates a nice ridgeline plot:
library("tidyverse")
library("ggridges")

set.seed(1992)                                       # Set seed for reproducibility
example <- data.frame(day = 0, month = 0, temperature = 0)  # Create empty data

months_averages <- c(10, 11, 14, 18, 23, 26, 29, 32, 25 ,18, 14, 6)
months_sd <- c(3, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 5, 5, 4, 7, 4, 3)

for(i in 1:12) {                                     # Fill up data with random numbers
  example[(i*30 - 29):(i*30), "day"] <- 
    1:30
  example[(i*30 - 29):(i*30), "month"] <- 
    month.name[i]
  example[(i*30 - 29):(i*30), "temperature"] <-
    rnorm(n = 30, 
          mean = months_averages[i],
          sd = months_sd[i]) %>%
    round()
}

example$month <-                                     # Convert month variable into a factor
  example$month %>% 
  as_factor()


ridge_density_plot <-                                # Draw densities in ridgeline plot
  example %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = temperature , y = month,  fill = month)) +
  ggridges::geom_density_ridges(scale = 1)           # Overlap among histograms
ridge_density_plot


Now, I would like to add maximum, minimum, mode value and an extra temperature value from an external model to the plot (for each month). How can it be done?


Did you try: stat_density_ridges(quantile_lines = TRUE) ? https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggridges/vignettes/introduction.html

Thanks, it shows the quantiles (even though sometimes the mode value is not correct). Is there a way to display the values as quantile labels?

See linked post, we can use custom functions.
